# complex query with solrnet

Tags: solr, solrnet

How can I build complex queries like this solr query with solrnet.

```
q=*:* & fq=(Code1:("N02" +OR+ "N01") +OR+ Code2:"B0") 
  +OR+ (*:* AND -Flg:G) +OR+ Id:"\-30"*
```

I want to use filter queries

1. with logical operations combined with expression

   ex: all cars ((red or green) or automatic)
2. with not operation

   ex: all cars except white ones
3. with wild card

   ex: all cars with make starting 'mit'
4. with parameters which need to be escaped

   ex: all cars with id starting with '-30'

Comment: Please provide more examples of what you have tried to do.

Comment: @Oyeme I have added examples of what I tried to achieve in the solr query mentioned.

Comment: have tried this  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet

Answer (score 0):

with logical operations combined with expression

ex: all cars ((red or green) or automatic)

Ans:  car_color:( red OR green ) OR car_transmission:( automatic )

with not operation

ex: all cars except white ones

Ans :  -car_color:( white )
- is spl char used to donate not in solr query

with wild card

ex: all cars with make starting 'mit'

Ans: car_make:mit*
* is a wild char represents 0 or more

with parameters which need to be escaped

ex: all cars with id starting with '-30'

Ans: car_id:( -30* )
- is a spl char in solr so it needs to escaped using \ char

Comment: thanks. I needed the way to build this query in solrnet, the .net client library. I have the solr query for it, which I mentioned in the question.